# How do you compare the values (not index) of two differently sized arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have two arrays (items and idValues). **Items** represents polygons (projects) on a map that are selected and contains their id values. **idValues** is an array that contains the ids of information cards on the side for each project.

When I filter my map, I want to take the selected ids of the selected polygons and compare those ids to the id values of my project information cards on the side so that, if I select only projects conducted in 2011 on the map, I will only see the project information cards that correspond to those 2011 projects.

The problem for me is that when I try to compare the arrays, they seem to compare by index and not by value which gives me the wrong result and if I try to change the filter selection, it ends up filtering the already filtered array instead of restarting from the whole idValues array.For example:

```
idValues = [10-001, 10-002, 10-003, 11-004, 11-005, 11-006, 12-007, 12-008];
items = [11-004, 11-005, 11-006];
//I only want to show the cards that have idValues == to items values, but they are compared by index:
//10-001 !== 11-004
//10-002 !== 11-005 etc...
```

How do I compare each value of an array to another when they have different lengths? And how do I make sure each time I change the filter requirements that it's a new query and filtering the already made selection? Is there a post here that I haven't seen that may answer my question?

My code is below, thanks for any help!

```
require([
"esri/map",
"esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
"esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",
"esri/dijit/Legend",
"dojo/_base/array",
"dojo/on",
"dojo/dom",
"dojo/dom-construct",
"dojo/domReady!"
], function(
Map, 
FeatureLayer, 
PopupTemplate, 
Legend,
array,
on,
dom,
domConst

) {

var map = new Map("viewDiv", {
  basemap: "gray-vector",
  center: [ -85.20127, 35.12355 ],
  zoom: 1
});

//Add layer to the map
var serviceUrl = "https://services2.arcgis.com/C8EMgrsFcRFL6LrL/arcgis/rest/services/HISAProjects_WFL1/FeatureServer/0?token=_3OEVd8Vn48n6NCc5StDZJZXhDbQmb6T3mqGZSNDqOQeg9whVAFaSgX2TnzlRsAy9R2CtzlrgdTk-ytdSxkYUyeQJEMV_r4v2hJska2KFGgC9ihtGe0twoO6zCZxcYfycDQmf80zvfRSoI8OtNQWYXLArn0yGc1WnvSInTMd8jm46yLvekFaQOmznJEtX73-bratx_zJGjN_SQ02s4kkgkgveg463iw7Ub1TIr0kjos";
var layer = new FeatureLayer(serviceUrl, {
  outFields: [ "FY", "HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_2", "HISAProjects_final_1262017_csv1", "HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_4", "HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_5", "HISAProjects_final_1262017_csv_", "HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_3", "HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_1", "HabitatData12_4_17_ProjectNum"],



  infoTemplate: new PopupTemplate({
    title: "{HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_4}",
    description: "<br />Lead PI: {HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_5}"
      + "<br />Region: {HISAProjects_final_1262017_csv_}"
      + "<br />Year: {FY}"
      + "<br />Primary Habitat Type: {HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_2}"
      + "<br />Secondary Habitat Type: {HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_3}"
      + "<br />Distance from shore: {HISAProjects_final_1262017_csv1}"
      + "<br />Secondary Distance from shore: {HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_1}"

      //
     // "Learn more.." link connected to individual main-areaCard info windows


  })
});   

map.addLayer(layer);
var legend = new Legend({
    map: map,
    layerInfos: [{
      layer: layer,
      title: "Habitat Type"
    }]
  }, "legendDiv");
// "Global" Variables
var filter1 = document.getElementById("filterhabitat");
var filter2 = document.getElementById("filterlocation");
var filter3 = document.getElementById("filteryear");  
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var idValues = [];
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("clickable");
//console.log(elem);
//console.log(elem.attributes);

map.on("load", function(evt){
  legend.startup();

    for(var i = 0; i < elem.length; ++i){
        if(elem[i].attributes.id.value != "undefined"){
          if(elem[i].attributes.id.value){
            var elements = elem[i].attributes.id.value;
            idValues.push(elements);

          } 
        }
      } //end for loop
      console.log("idValues: " + idValues);    

  button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    habitatValue = filter1.options[filter1.selectedIndex].value;
    distanceValue = filter2.options[filter2.selectedIndex].value;
    yearValue = filter3.options[filter3.selectedIndex].value;

    pushValues(habitatValue, distanceValue, yearValue);  

  });
}); //end of map event function
function pushValues (habitatValue, distanceValue, yearValue){
  var expressionArray = [];
  if (habitatValue) {
    var str = `HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_2 = '${habitatValue}'`;    
    expressionArray.push(str);
  }

  if (distanceValue) {
    var str = `HISAProjects_final_1262017_csv1 = '${distanceValue}'`;
    expressionArray.push(str);
  }
  if (yearValue) {
    var str = `FY = '${yearValue}'`;
    expressionArray.push(str);
  }

  console.log(expressionArray);
  var definitionExpression = expressionArray.join(' AND ');

  updateDefinitionExpression(definitionExpression);
}


function updateDefinitionExpression(definitionExpression){ 

    //var definitionExpression = "HISAProjects_final_1262017_cs_2 = 'PELAGIC' AND FY = '2010'";
    layer.setDefinitionExpression(definitionExpression);
    layer.on('update-end', function(evt){
    var projNumArr = [];    
   array.map(layer.graphics, function(gra){
      projNumArr.push(gra.attributes.HabitatData12_4_17_ProjectNum);

     });
   var items = projNumArr;
      // console.log("items: " + items);
      // console.log("ids: " + idValues);

      for(i in idValues){
        console.log("items: " + items[i]);
        console.log("idValues: " + idValues[i]);
        if(idValues.length > 0){
            if (idValues[i] !== items[i]){
                $("#" + idValues[i]).hide();
            }
        }
      }     

    }); //END HERE

    map.infoWindow.hide();      

}//end updateDefinitionExpression function

}); // end Function
```

Comment: It's a little hard to figure out exactly what you are trying to do — your talking about `cards` but I don't see anything representing cards. You would be better off making a simple example that distills your problem in something that's easy for a stranger to reproduce.

Comment: I don't know if you have a typo for your `idValues` but if those are supposed to actually be `10-001` then you need to make them a string...because once the code runs, it's doing math and making it a number value of `9` (10 minus 1). So your idValues is actually `[9, 8, 7, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming the code you want to replace is this block:

```
for(i in idValues){
  console.log("items: " + items[i]);
  console.log("idValues: " + idValues[i]);
  if(idValues.length > 0){
    if (idValues[i] !== items[i]){
      $("#" + idValues[i]).hide();
    }
  }
}
```

You can get the functionality you want using Array [`.map`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) and [`.indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp) functionality:

```
idValues.map(function (v) {
  if (!items.indexOf(v)) $("#" + v).hide();
});
```

This code will hide any `idValues` which are not present in `items`.